# Is there a way to search a field in a JSON array that can contain multiple values for a specific value?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, rest

I have an ajax query that returns results and should display them in an html table like the below:

```html
<input type="button" value="Customer" onclick="SelectCustomer()">
<input type="button" value="Advisor" onclick="SelectAdvisor()">
<input type="button" value="Get Results" onclick="GetResults()">
<table id="results">
</table>
```

I'm wanting to filter this based on the affected area, so to show lists only items with a status of Open, and only impacting specific areas, such as Advisors, or Customers, etc.  The current code I have to do this works in so far as it filters for Status, but I only get a blank return when I'm trying to filter the Affected Area field.  I've been working with using JavaScript variables to contain information regarding whether a value has been selected or not, which is what I'm trying to filter against, however the filter script I have that shows only items with a Status value of Open doesn't seem to work for me if I have multiple values in the field.

```js
var dResponse = [
    {"Reference": "123456","Status": "Open","AffectedArea": ["IT","Advisor"]}
    {"Reference": "654321","Status": "Closed","AffectedArea": ["Customer","IT"]}
    {"Reference": "567889","Status": "Open","AffectedArea": ["Advisor","Customer"]}
    {"Reference": "987654","Status": "Open","AffectedArea": ["Customer"]}
]
var custSelect = "Unselected";
var adviSelect = "Unselected";
var custfil = "";
var advifil = "";

function SelectCustomer(){
    if (custSelect == "Unselected") {
        custSelect = "Selected";
        adviSelect = "Unselected";
    } else {
        custSelect = "Unselected";
    }
}
function SelectAdvisor(){
    if (adviSelect == "Unselected") {
        adviSelect = "Selected";
        custSelect = "Unselected";
    } else {
        adviSelect = "Unselected";
    }
}

function GetResults() {
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var filResponse = dResponse.filter(function(item){
        return item.Status == "Open";
    })
    if (custSelect == "Selected"){
        FilterCust();
    }
    if (adviSelect ==" Selected"){
        FilterAdvi();
    }
    results.innerHTML += "<tr><td>Reference</td><td>Status</td><td>Affected Area</td></tr>";
    for(var obj in filResponse){
        results.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + dResponse[obj].Reference + "</td><td>" + dResponse[obj].Status + "</td><td>" + dResponse[obj].AffectedArea + "</td></tr>";
    }
}

function FilterCust() {
 filResponse = dResponse.filter(function(item){
  return item.ImpactedArea == "Customer";
})
}
function FilterAdvi() {
 filResponse = dResponse.filter(function(item){
  return item.ImpactedArea == "Advisor";
})
}
```

Admittedly, I'm not sure how the JSON results display multiple values in the same field, however the results come from a REST query to a SharePoint list, and the script works from that, the above was to give an idea regarding what sort of data the JSON table has in it.

Comment: var filResponse = dResponse.filter(function(item){
        return item.Status == "Open" || item.Status.some(c => c == "Open");
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing individual variable of `custSelect`, `adviSelect`. I will suggest you to store into an array instead. It will be more clean and easier to do. Later you can utilize array [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function to do the filtering.

```html
<input type="button" value="Customer" onclick="handleOnChange(this.value)" />
<input type="button" value="Advisor" onclick="handleOnChange(this.value)" />
<input type="button" value="Get Results" onclick="GetResults()" />
<table id="results">
  <!-- Table content will be created with Javascript -->
</table>
```

```js
<script>
  const dResponse = [
    {
      Reference: '123456',
      Status: 'Open',
      AffectedArea: ['IT', 'Advisor']
    },
    {
      Reference: '654321',
      Status: 'Closed',
      AffectedArea: ['Customer', 'IT']
    },
    {
      Reference: '567889',
      Status: 'Open',
      AffectedArea: ['Advisor', 'Customer']
    },
    {
      Reference: '987654',
      Status: 'Open',
      AffectedArea: ['Customer']
    }
  ];

  let selectedArea = [];
  const handleOnChange = value => {
    const index = selectedArea.findIndex(a => a === value);
    if (index > -1) {
      selectedArea.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      selectedArea.push(value);
    }
  };

  const GetResults = () => {
    const results = document.getElementById('results');
    const filResponse = dResponse.filter(item => item.Status == 'Open' && selectedArea.some(a => item.AffectedArea.indexOf(a) > -1));
    results.innerHTML +=
      '<tr><td>Reference</td><td>Status</td><td>Affected Area</td></tr>';
    filResponse.forEach(item => {
      results.innerHTML +=
        '<tr><td>' +
        item.Reference +
        '</td><td>' +
        item.Status +
        '</td><td>' +
        item.AffectedArea +
        '</td></tr>';
    });
  };
</script>
```

### Update (11/22/2019) :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .selected {
        background: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="GetResults(event)">
      <input type="button" name="AffectedArea" value="IT" onclick="handleToggleOnChange(this)" />
      <input type="button" name="AffectedArea" value="Customer" onclick="handleToggleOnChange(this)" />
      <input type="button" name="AffectedArea" value="Advisor" onclick="handleToggleOnChange(this)" />
      <select name="Status" onchange="handleSelectOnChange(this)">
        <option value="Open" selected="selected">Open</option>
        <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <table id="results">
      <!-- Table content will be created with Javascript -->
    </table>
    <script>
      const dResponse = [
        {
          Reference: "123456",
          Status: "Open",
          AffectedArea: ["IT", "Advisor"]
        },
        {
          Reference: "654321",
          Status: "Closed",
          AffectedArea: ["Customer", "IT"]
        },
        {
          Reference: "567889",
          Status: "Open",
          AffectedArea: ["Advisor", "Customer"]
        },
        {
          Reference: "987654",
          Status: "Open",
          AffectedArea: ["Customer"]
        }
      ];

      // Store form's filter data
      const formData = {
        AffectedArea: [],
        Status: 'Open',
      }

      const handleToggleOnChange = input => {
        const { name, value } = input;
        const index = formData[name].findIndex(a => a === value);
        if (index > -1) {
          input.classList.remove('selected');
          formData[name].splice(index, 1);
        } else {
          input.classList.add('selected');
          formData[name].push(value);
        }
        // Log your formData
        console.log(formData);
      };

      const handleSelectOnChange = (select) => {
        const { name, value } = select;
        formData[name] = value;
        // Log your formData
        console.log(formData);
      }

      const createRow = () => document.createElement("tr");

      const createColumn = (text, colspan) => {
        const column = document.createElement("td");
        const textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
        column.appendChild(textNode);
        column.setAttribute('colspan', colspan);
        return column;
      };

      const GetResults = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const results = document.getElementById("results");
        const filResponse = dResponse.filter(
          item =>
            // Status must be Open
            item.Status == formData.Status &&
            // Item's AffectedArea's array includes one of the selected area
            formData.AffectedArea.some(a => item.AffectedArea.indexOf(a) > -1)
        );
        // Clear previous result
        while (results.firstChild) {
          results.firstChild.remove();
        }
        // Create header row
        const headerRow = createRow();
        let headerKeys = [];
        if (dResponse.length > 0) {
          headerKeys = Object.keys(dResponse[0]);
          headerKeys.forEach(key => {
            headerRow.appendChild(createColumn(key));
          });
        }
        results.appendChild(headerRow);
        // Create content result rows
        if (filResponse.length > 0) {
          const rows = [];
          filResponse.forEach(item => {
            const row = createRow();
            Object.values(item).forEach(value => {
              row.appendChild(createColumn(value));
            });
            rows.push(row);
          });
          if (rows.length > 0) {
            rows.forEach(r => {
              results.appendChild(r);
            });
          }
        } else {
          // Create no results found row
          const row = createRow();
          row.appendChild(createColumn("No results found", headerKeys.length));
          results.appendChild(row);
        }
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've created a simple working demo of the array filtering implementation. I've tried to avoid using `innerHTML`, you can use your own rendering method.
**Further updated my answer to provide more options to choose from.**

Working Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/html-filter-table-demo-qm19r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Would this work if I wanted to be able to toggle filers on?  such as showing items tagged for ```Advisor``` AND ```Customer``` rather than OR?

Comment: @GetWhimsical Yes, this will allow you to filter based on multiple values. I will try to update my answer to provide a clearer working demo